# Any suggestions as to clear these errors for floating nav bar in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I have a little navigation bar with only one selection that is in a fixed position on the page, listed for contacts. I got a whole bunch of errors that basically said:

- ***Error: Element h3 not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) From line
  267, column 5; to line 267, column 24    `<ul>`↩             `<h3
  class="heading">Emerge`***
- ***Error: Element h4 not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.) From line

  268, column 5; to line 268, column 8 `</h3>`↩                `<h4>Contact1`***

***And so on...***

I have already set it up the way I want it to work, I don't want to change anything CSS wise with it. Upon click it's supposed to open, and with me getting rid of the `<ul>` tag, it messes everything up.

Here is the working code version: https://jsfiddle.net/jgg7kqv4/2/

Here is what it should look like, and should stay looking like:

[![examplescreenshot][1]][1]

This is the basic HTML:

```
<aside>
    <ul id="contact">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="contact"/>
            <label for="contact" name="contact">Contact</label>
            <ul>
                <h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3>
                <h4>Contact1</h4>
                <p class="underline"><a href="#">LINK</a></p>
                <h4>Contact2</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday: 8 am - 4 pm</p>
                <p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p>
                <h4>Contact3</h4>
                <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 10am - 6pm</p>
                <p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p>
                <p>Location</p>
                <p class="underline"><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></p>
                <h4>Email contact</h4>
                <p class="underline">noemail@noemail.com</p>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

***EDIT: Updated JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/jgg7kqv4/2/***

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your content with a `li` tag:

```
    <ul>
        <li style="display: block">
            <h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3>
            <h4>Contact1</h4>
            <p class="underline"><a href="#">LINK</a></p>
            <h4>Contact2</h4>
            <p class="italic">Monday - Friday: 8 am - 4 pm</p>
            <p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p>
            <h4>Contact3</h4>
            <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 10am - 6pm</p>
            <p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p>
            <p>Location</p>
            <p class="underline"><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></p>
            <h4>Email contact</h4>
            <p class="underline">noemail@noemail.com</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Look at the edit at the error it created because of the CSS! I can't change any of the CSS unfortunately.

https://jsfiddle.net/jgg7kqv4/1/

Comment: Can you add inline CSS? The problem is your `<ul>` tag can only have `<li>` tags as children elements.

Comment: @tomaroo This has both the HTML and CSS: jsfiddle.net/jgg7kqv4/1

Answer (score 0):

Make your `h3`, `h4`, `p` tags inside `<li>`

```html
<aside>
    <ul id="contact">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="contact"/>
            <label for="contact" name="contact">Contact</label>
            <ul>
                <li><h3 class="heading">Emergency Contacts</h3></li>
                <li><h4>Contact1</h4></li>
                <li><p class="underline"><a href="#">LINK</a></p></li>
                <h4>Contact2</h4>
                 <li><p class="italic">Monday - Friday: 8 am - 4 pm</p> </li>
                 <li><p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p> </li>
                 <li><h4>Contact3</h4> </li>
                <li> <p class="italic">Monday - Friday; 10am - 6pm</p> </li>
                 <li><p>Phone number: ###-###-####</p> </li>
                 <li><p>Location</p> </li>
                <li> <p class="underline"><a href="#">WEBSITE</a></p> </li>
                 <li><h4>Email contact</h4> </li>
                 <li><p class="underline">noemail@noemail.com</p> </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

Comment: Look at the edit I've put in to your post to see what happened to it after I tried what you suggested. It starts highlighting all the <li> elements upon hover.

Comment: Sarangheh510 is talking about [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14490290).